# Mock new Date() in Deno

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, deno

I'm wondering if anyone has been able to implement something like `jest.spyOn(global, 'Date').mockImplementation(() => now);` inside of Deno.

I have looked through the documentation for the mock in the Deno documentation [here](https://deno.land/std@0.170.0/testing/mock.ts) and I have looked through the mock time [here](https://deno.land/x/mock@0.15.2/time.ts) however this doesn't look like it will replace the `new Date()` with the mocked implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite any global variable directly — they're accessible as properties/methods on [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis).

Here's an example (that's not specific to any testing framework) which replaces the global [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class with an example class that also has a method named `toString`:

```js
class Example {
  toString() {
    return "This is just an example";
  }
}

function overwriteDateAndReturnRestoreFn() {
  const originalDate = globalThis.Date;
  globalThis.Date = Example;
  return () => void (globalThis.Date = originalDate);
}

console.log(new Date().toString()); //=> <A string represetning the actual current date>

const restore = overwriteDateAndReturnRestoreFn();
console.log(new Date().toString()); //=> "This is just an example"

restore();
console.log(new Date().toString()); //=> <A string represetning the actual current date>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, This wont watch for a call of `Date()` in other functions that are running in the test and return a different value will it, It will only return the new values within it's own test is that correct?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76369343/mock-new-date-in-deno/76373884?noredirect=1#comment134696238_76373884) @Ataxote I'm not sure what you mean: if you are referring to the example code — it's self-contained — there's nothing more than what you see there.

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation. I have a function that I am trying to test. Within the function there are two calls to `new Date()` I know that in some test operation you can spy on a function and if that function is called return my value instead of whatever the function would normally return.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76369343/mock-new-date-in-deno/76373884?noredirect=1#comment134712049_76373884) @Ataxote I’m not sure how what you described is different than the code shown.

Answer (score 0):

To mock `new Date` on Deno, you can use [`@sinonjs/fake-timers`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sinonjs/fake-timers)

```
import FakeTimers from "npm:@sinonjs/fake-timers";
import { assertEquals, assertNotEquals } from "https://deno.land/std@0.190.0/testing/asserts.ts";

Deno.test("New Year", () => {
  const clock = FakeTimers.install();
  clock.setSystemTime(new Date('2020-01-01'));

  // Happy New Year
  assertEquals(new Date().toDateString(), 'Wed Jan 01 2020');
  clock.uninstall();
});

Deno.test("now", () => {
  // Not Happy New Year
  assertNotEquals(new Date().toDateString(), 'Wed Jan 01 2020');
});
```

---

If you're already using jest, you can use `jest.useFakeTimers()` with [`.setSystemTime(now?: number | Date)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestsetsystemtimenow-number--date)

```
jest
  .useFakeTimers()
  .setSystemTime(new Date('2020-01-01'));
```

And to restore to real timers after you're done, you should call [`jest.useRealTimers()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestuserealtimers)